# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError (Unknown Format)

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I recently began researching tensorflow, since the neural networks I created on my own were extremely slow. I am using my own [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/histopathologic-cancer-detection/data?select=train_labels.csv) of (96 * 96 * 3) sized colored images as my inputs and a list of single integer as my outputs, split up into 8 batches.

Here is my code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
print('Imports Sucessfull')

path = 'D:\\Data'
labelsFile = open(f'{path}train_labels.csv')
labels = [row.split(',') for row in labelsFile.read().split('\n')][1:-1]
labelsFile.close()

filenames, results = [], []
for row in labels:
    filenames.append(f'{path}train\\{row[0]}.tif')
    results.append([int(row[1])])

filenames = tf.constant(filenames)
results = tf.constant(results)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, results))
```

Here is the portion I suspect is problematic:

```
def form(filename, result):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    return image, result

dataset = dataset.map(form)
dataset = dataset.batch(8)

iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
images, labels = iterator.get_next()
```

However, my code returns the following error on `images, labels = iterator.get_next()`:

```py
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected image 
(JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with 
'II*\000\010\000\000\000\017\000\376\000\004\000\001\000'
         [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
```

I am pretty certain this is happening because my input or output lists are not formatted properly in `dataset`, but I don't know why, or how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.tff` is not yet supported in tf.data API. Though there is one experimental package, https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/image/decode_tiff or check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044742/tensorflow-how-to-use-tensorflows-dataset-api-to-use-tiff-images

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this today. Hopefully packaging the tif files won't be too slow.